# Doxygen for documenting overloaded functions with variable parameters

Tags: c++, doxygen, variadic-functions, overloading

Is it possible to make doxygen to create proper documentation for code like this:

```
void Print(const char* pszFormat, ...);
void Print(const wchar_t* pszFormat, ...);
```

I have two problems with this code. First I can't refer to both of these functions from other parts of my code.
For `\ref Print(const char*, ...);` and `\ref Print(const wchar_t*, ...);` links to only one of the above declarations are generated.

Also the variable arguments are placed in a predefined format which has to be described. Trying to use the '\param' tag for it leads to warnings about the parameters are not found in the function declaration. Since I have multiple of such functions I would like to get rid of the warnings specifically for this case if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

If you specify the parameter literally as ..., it will be picked up by Doxygen. E.g. as follows:`\param[in] ... Arguments for format specification`. This will appear properly in your generated documentation.

No clue about the disambiguation of the `const char*` and `const wchar_t*` though.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT`, which by default is already enabled, it should work **without** including `\ref`. That is - Doxygen sees things that might be linkable names, and tries to figure them out for you without you explicitly calling them references. I just tested an example:

```
/// Get 8 bits of foo
/// @param blah The blah to foo
void getFoo(uint8_t blah) = 0;

/// Get 16 bits of foo
/// @param blah The blah to foo
void getFoo(uint16_t blah) = 0;

/// First, look at getFoo(uint8_t) for info,
/// then look at getFoo(uint16_t) for more
void getBar() = 0;
```

And the two links created in `getBar()` documentation pointed to the respective functions.

FWIW I'm using doxygen (`version 1.86`) for C++, but I don't have any C or C++ optimizations turned on, and I have `JAVA_DOC` and `QT` enabled, so I don't think it should much matter if your example was C++ or Java, but I'm not positive.

As for your second question, the first thing that came to mind was using a code block to *show* what the variable arguments should be, but I don't know if that's sufficient for your needs. For example

```
/// Bar some foos with extra arguments
/// @param foo The foo we totally want to bar
/// @return true if we barred
/// Typical usage requires that we either supply the number of times to bar
///  followed by some other baz ...
/// @code
/// uint8_t nbars = 12; // must be uint8_t because of some reason
/// Baz baz = new Baz(); // or some old Baz lying around, doesn't matter
/// bool isBarred = bar(foo, nbars, baz);
/// @code
/// ... OR, we need to supply a list of Baz's, so we know what to do
/// @code
/// Baz manyBaz[]; 
/// // fill in manyBaz with whatever Baz's you want
/// bool isBarred - bar(foo, manyBaz);
/// @code
bool bar(foo, ...);
```

This way, your documentation makes it as clear as it possibly can, without actually resorting to polymorphic (non-variadic) functions that can each have explicit `@param` arguments. While it may look like a large jumble of text written here, running that through doxygen will make it clearer and (in my opinion) pretty readable for some user of your code/documentation.